# ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side

Tags: postgresql

We are calling the  proc  `public.update_records (p_record_id integer, p_notification_list text)` 
and assigning the p_notification_list value as

```
ct.new_notification_id::text = ANY(string_to_array(p_notification_list,','))
```

and the value of the p_notification_list passed is `'<notification_id_1>','<notification_id_2>'`  and so on

and getting the error as **op ANY/ALL (array) requires array on right side**

Please suggest

Comment: Can you please share the entire procedure's code?

Comment: We need the context of this statement. And your version of Postgres. Is it supposed to be a plpgsql assignment? Or a test for equality in an SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me:

```
regress=> SELECT 'a' = ANY (string_to_array('a,b,c', ','));
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

so I think whatever's wrong isn't shown in this question. This is why you need to show *whole statements*, your Pg version, table definitions, etc.